# How can I get the audio or video duration of selected file in angular form

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-forms, angular-file-upload

In my angular form, I get my video or audio files by

```
(change)="fileSelected($event)
```

in .html form and

```
attachedFile = <File>event.target.files[0]
```

in .ts file that has name, type and size. How can I get audio/video duration time?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an audio or video element dynamically based on selected file type and then can get other info. Here is the code...

```
fileSelected($event) {
  attachedFile = <File>event.target.files[0]

  let duration:any;

  //here you can check the file type for attachedFile either video or audio

  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.preload = 'metadata';

  video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
    duration = video.duration; // here you could get the duration
  }

  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(attachedFile);
}
```

Comment: there's minor difference, the file system on computer may have used round figure to show the duration. this is showing the exact time.

Comment: here, duration variable is not accessible outside of its scope and only could log inside of that, so it couldn't use as a variable for fileSelected function

Comment: You can use global variable for that, there you should use your own logic. I just provided you the guidance.

Comment: global variable isnt problem because of execute set duration variable and run rest of code are together so even global variable will be undefined. as I said in your code set var duration only works beside it and if you even call duration variable beside video.src, you will get undefined response because in that scope there isnt any duration variable. you can check   video.src = URL.createObjectURL(attachedFile);
console.log(duration); //undefined

Comment: Updated the answer, please check now.

Comment: if it still not works, then you can return promise from this function. It'll sure work for you.

Comment: It's work fine. But i can't assign `duration` value to my public varible like this `this.durationTime = video.duration;`

Comment: @JigneshPanchal
change 
video.onloadedmetadata = function() {

to 

video.onloadedmetadata = () => {

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
    attachedFile.addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => {
       // Your code.
    });
```